# Using negative integer range of int (4 bytes) as ids(-2.14 billion to 0) : Any downsides?

Tags: java, database, database-design

I am storing certain entities in my database with `integer` Ids of size 32 bits thus using the range of -2.14 billion to +2.14 billion.

I have given tried giving some meaning to my ids due to which my Ids, in the positive range, have finished up a bit quickly. I am looking forward to use the negative integer range of -2.14 billion to 0.

Wanted to know, if you could see any downsides of using negative integers as ids, though personally I don't see any downsides.

Comment: Are you aiming at a specific database, or intending to match your Java program up to various different ones?

Comment: why long not BigInteger?

Comment: @Suresh, the smaller the key size, the faster the index and less memory it takes into the memory.

Comment: @Suresh - because it is unlikely that the system will run for long enough to go through 2^64 id values.  (Ignoring optimization, estimate how `long l = 0; while(l++ > 0) {}` takes to finishes ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given than dumb keys are only compared for equality, sign or lack thereof has no impact.

Answer (score 3):

There is an old saying in database design that goes like this: "Intelligent keys are not".  You should never design for special meaning in an id when a descriptive attribute is more appropriate.

Comment: yes but could you list any downsides of the same ? that would to great to hear! thanks!

Comment: Which is more descriptive to you?

Comment: Which is more descriptive to you? `select * from calls where id < 0` or `select * from calls where slow = 1`.  the point is technically you can do it but your code requires comments which are not reliable.  Later someone else can change the schema removing the signed integer and you application will break for some unknown reason to the next person who doesn't know the trick you used.